# Can you loop a flipper animation based on users entry?

Tags: android

In the example below there is layout with an entry field and button. The user would enter a number between 0 and 10 and the flipper would animate from screen 10 to the number entered.

If I comment out the **for(int i=10; .....;i--){** on the onClick the screens slides fine each time you click the button. If I put in the for loop in the screen goes straight to the screen number without sliding each screen. The loop goes too fast for the animation to catchup.

Is it possible to have it so that if you enter 2 for example the flipper would go:

Flipper 10

Slide animation occurs

Flipper 9

Slide animation occurs

Flipper 8
  .....

main activity:

```
package com.jk.flippertest;

import com.jk.flippertest.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class FlipperTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Animation slideRightIn;
private Animation slideRightOut;
private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
TextView loopNumber;
int loopValue;
Button goBtn;
ViewFlipper fSpace;
LayoutInflater inflater;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    loopNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    goBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);       

    fSpace = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for (int i=0;i<11;i++){
        TextView tvi = new TextView(this);
        tvi.setText("Flipper "+i);
        tvi.setTextSize(50);
        tvi.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        LinearLayout lli = new LinearLayout(this);
        lli = new LinearLayout(this);
        lli.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        lli.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        lli.addView(tvi);

        fSpace.addView(lli);
        }

        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
        slideRightIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
        slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_out);

        goBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Value is "+loopNumber.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for(int i=10;i>=Integer.parseInt(loopNumber.getText().toString());i--){
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);                     
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                }
            }
        });

}
```

}

main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Enter numb between 0 to 10.">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go" />

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

slide_right_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="800"/>
</set>
```

slide_right_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p" android:duration="800"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for slide_right_out.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you play with loop, just use Timer for it and place a delay of time (1 sec ..) and in  that just change your views(slides).

**EDIT:**

[CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

[Updating the UI from a Timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)

Comment: Thanks dmon but I'm not sure how a timer would work. I'll try and find some examples of timers and flip views. If someone could attach some sample code to get me started that would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at my edited answer, you can find a link for how to use timer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the links but I could not see how to use the Timer. I found some examples on handlers and used that.  The code below seems to work but not sure if I got it 100% correct.

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                loopToNumber();
            }
        });
}
protected void loopToNumber() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i=10;i>=Integer.parseInt(loopNumber.getText().toString());i--){ 
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1600);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            delayHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
private Handler delayHandler = new Handler() {  
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
        viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);                     
        viewFlipper.showPrevious();
    }
};
```